# Is The Dirac Delta Communitive Over a Cross Product?

Tags: vector-analysis, dirac-delta

Is the statement,

$\delta(\vec{x}) \vec{A}\times \vec{B} \equiv  \vec{A}\times \vec{B}\  \delta(\vec{x}) $

True?  If so, how would I go about proving this?

Comment: Are $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ constant or are they vector fields depending on $\vec{x}$?

Comment: They are vector fields that depend on $\vec{x}$

Comment: How do you consider the associations? Is it
$$\left( \delta(\vec{x}) \, \vec{A} \right) \times \vec{B} = \vec{A} \times \left( \vec{B} \, \delta(\vec{x}) \right)$$
or
$$\delta(\vec{x}) \, \left( \vec{A} \times \vec{B} \right) = \left( \vec{A} \times \vec{B} \right) \, \delta(\vec{x})$$
or something else?